# Django CreateView Trying to register a client With a specific number that goes from 15 to 15

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to make a small system in which I have to put a client number that goes from 15 to 15, but the truth is that I did not succeed to change a global variable.

I am trying to learn how class based views work.

I hope you can help me.

What I'm looking for is to get the find the last record in the database and add 15 to it.

thank you.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    customer_num = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
from re import template
from django.shortcuts import render
from aplicacion.models import *
from django.views.generic import *
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

class CreateCustomer(CreateView):
    model = Customer
    template_name = 'createcustomer.html'
    fields = ['name']
    success_url = "/admin/aplicacion/customer/"

    aa = Customer.objects.last().customer_num
    def form_valid(self, form):
        global aa
                
        while True:
            
            try:
                Customer = form.save(commit=False)
                Customer.customer_num = self.aa
                print(self.aa, "jjjj")
                """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
                #form.instance.customer_num = self.request.POST['name']
                break
                aa = self.aa + 15

            except:    
                pass            

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: i think you can play with the customer's pk to make this easy to do.by example you can take the customer's pk + 15.

Comment: As you say, I could take the pk and only add 15. The problem is that I am trying to make a more robust system, but above all to understand how class-based views work and what I want to do is have unique client numbers. I give you an example. A-001, A-002, In the event that this customer number exists, I would like it to be increased, but it would have to be in that format, but for that I would have to know exactly how these views work. First of all. Do this little exercise.

Comment: This little system is supposed to take the first letter of the name and then add a consecutive number. like A-001, A-002, A-003, A-301for example

Answer (score 0):

No need for global or anything "fancy".

Define a simple function preferably in the view-file after importing your model:

```
def get_new_customer_num():
    from django.db.models import Max
    biggestNumber = Customer.objects.aggregate(Max('customer_num')["customer_num__max"]
    return biggestNumber+15
```

Call this function wherever you need a new customer-number like

```
customer_num = get_new_customer_num()
```

I would suggest that the prefix "first letter of the name" etc. is only used in display, so u only have to deal with unique numbers, that's faster and simpler …
For display you could build a function for the model (like like the **str**()-function) calculating a nice customer number like jd_21375 for a customer John/Jane Doe.